# Catch SimpleXML Exception only?

Tags: php, exception, simplexml

SimpleXML throws a regular Exception, how could I differentiate this from other exceptions if the class is the same?

Comment: What method in `SimpleXML` throws an exception? You might be able to extend SimpleXML, catch this exception and then rethrow your own.

Comment: Rethrowing is something I'd like to avoid. I've seen a lot of ReflectionExceptions out of nowhere when doing it, which should be of other exception classes. By the way it's the constructor that gives the exceptions that the XML to be parsed is not valid. Actually, it's a timing issue that rarely occurs when two processess try to access the same XML file at the same time, thus one of the file_get_contents functions returns an empty string (the file was locked), which is of course invalid XML. I want to handle these exceptions.

Comment: Can you prevent those two processes from fighting over the file? Can you lock the file for reading or writing to prevent this? That sounds like the root cause that needs fixing, rather than dealing with the mess it makes.

Comment: I don't know why ReflectionExceptions would be raised, but rethrowing exceptions is afaik quite normal, so that sounds like something that needs fixing anyway.

Comment: @halfer It's a more complex issue. I am using an external API for stock analysis that I have to query every 5 seconds. If for some reason the execution takes more than 5 seconds, they overlap in time. This is the matter of db query optimization and algorhytm refactoring. I can't really avoid the root cause at the moment, I just don't want it to spam all logs all the time.

Comment: @RápliAndrás: If you add an example on how to provoke such an exception you're talking about, it would be easier to give additional suggestions. Especially as you write that you use **SimpleXMLElement** as a collaborator within a layer in your application, even more should be possible.

Comment: @hakre It's a live data feed that serves new data every 5 seconds. Since a cronjob can be set to run not more often than every 1 minute, the rest of calculation must be done with the script that processes this XML. So at the moment a loop is responsible for this with a little bit of enhancement, where runtime is somewhat taken into consideration, however, in some cases, the last run might overlap with the first of the next batch, they try to access the same file at the same time - one of them being locked out, thus SimpleXML constructor receives empty string, which is not a valid XML.

Comment: So like `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('');` to provoke the exception?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you have is very local and can be easily handled.

Instead of using

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($buffer);
```

(the exception-case is that `$buffer = ''`)

You can make use of a function that tells you whether or not loading of the buffer did work w/o throwing an exception:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
```

In case of an error, `$xml` will be false. So you don't have the exception problem in the first place.

Additionally I suggest you make the code more stable as well if you're interested in more detailed error handling, like checking preconditions and postconditions for the function call:

```
if (!is_string($buffer) || !strlen($buffer)) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("String with length required");
}

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
if (!$xml) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('String could not be parsed as XML');
}
```

This also shows how you can throw the exceptions you like. However as you're only concerned about a single line of code you can just catch *any* exception and deal with the single error-case you have there:

```
try {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($buffer);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $xml = false;
}
```

But then, using `simplexml_load_string` might be more handy.

Next to that, you can also enable internal error reporting of libxml and find out more about the actual problems when creating the object:

```
$saved  = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml    = simplexml_load_string($buffer);
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($saved);

if (!$xml) {
    var_dump($errors); // create and throw a specific exception here based on errors.
}
```

However, an empty string won't create any error, better take care if it with a precondition check.

Additionally:

- Make the cron-job save to a different filename while donwloading, replacing the file only when ready.
- Open the file read-only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer, I didn't think it was this easy :)

Answer (score 3):

I made a workaround, catching and investigating the specific error message.

```
try{
    //...
}catch(Exception $e){
    if(!strstr($e->getMessage(), 'XML')) throw $e;
}
```

Then rethrowing everything not related to XML processing.